# Sql Server 2016 Always Encryption Not working

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2016

I am using sql server 2016 to use always encryption option. I have 2 server. I kept sql server 2016 in server and encrypted columns for my DB. I have hosted my MVC application in another server using iis. I am using entity framework to connect with sql. I have added the item column encryption setting=enabled; in my connection string. While running my application i am getting the below error.

Do we need to keep both sql and application in same server? what is the solution for below error?

**Error**
Certificate with thumbprint ... not found in certificate store 'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'. Verify the certificate path in the column master key definition in the database is correct, and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate location/store.

Answer (score 0):

You should export always encrypted certificate from Database Server mmc.exe console CurrentUser certificate location, you have already set encryption. Then, you should also import such certificate into Application Server mmc.exe console into CurrentUser certificate local.